# How to center content inside Row element

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to center some cards inside a row element but I cant get it to work!

```
        <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          {cardData.map((data) => {
            return (
              <Col>
                <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={data.img} />
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{data.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>{data.text}</Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary">{data.button}</Button>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            );
          })}
        </Row>
```

this is how it looks:: (as you can see, there is un-event spacing on the left and right of the card
[image: imageOfCards]

I tried to put the following classes (mx-auto,d-flex justify-content-center) on the parent row but I cant get it to work

any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Change your Row class from `justify-content-center` to `justify-content-between`.

Answer (score 1):

use `justify-content: space-between`

```
   <Row  style={{display:'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
```